# Riemann and Lebesgue integrals as sums of infimums

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Riemann integral (partitioning of the function domain):
$$
\int_a^b fdx = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \inf_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]}f(x)d\mu([x_{i-1}, x_i])
$$

Lebesgue integral (partitioning of the function range):
$$
\int_E fd\mu = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \inf_{E_k} f(x) \mu(E_k)
$$

**Questions:**

1) Are the definitions above correct?

2) How to derive these definitions and what is the logic behind them?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: An answer to a similar question might be helpful for 2): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642034/eli5-riemann-integrable-vs-lebesgue-integrable/1642090#1642090

Comment: Are the definitions correct?  Sort of.  If $f$ is integrable then those equations are true.  But the limit on the right may exist even if $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: What you have written is not "partition the domain" vs. "partition the range" ... You have written two different schemes to partition the domain: into intervals vs. into measurable sets.  See the answer linked by Roland for explanation of the "partition the range" scheme for the Lebesgue integral.